# Webpack can't resolve data:text import

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, compilation

My app uses a third party library that has the syntax:

```
const module = await import(`data:text/javascript;charset=utf-8,${content}`);
```

While building through Webpack I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@web/test-runner-commands/browser/commands.mjs
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'data:text' in 'C:\path_to_project\node_modules\@web\test-runner-commands\browser'
```

I tried using babel-loader in my Webpack config:

```
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.m?js$/,
            include: [
                path.resolve(workingDirectory, 'node_modules/@web')
            ],
            use: 'babel-loader'
        }
    ]
}
```

I need help figuring out what loader would be able to interpret the expression.